# Handling and parsing string with multiple elements to the form using one input

Tags: website-design, forms, web-app, input-fields

We have a problem that we want to solve in the most intuitive way.

There is a modal with one text input, but the requirements are for user to be able to put one OR multiple email in it. This is needed to send invites for those emails. Also for each email there should be a way to add a "role" before sending the invite.

Initially i was thinking that it can be the format of "inout - dropdown" and "+" or "add" below it so you put email, select the role and then tap "Add" if you need add more. It results in the same input - dropdown row rendering below the previous row and you just fill the list as long as you want.

But the product owner requires that user should be able to paste up to 25 emails separated by comma and you should be able to pick the role to each one before sending invites.

I proposed to put the instruction in the first input placeholder, like "Put one or multiple email seprated by comma" and as soon as they copypaste their email or start typuing and put ", " sequence, we gonna automatically add a new row.

What is the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to make it a two-step modal. The first modal has a `textarea` where users can paste in up to 25 comma-separated emails, then click "continue." The second step then shows a list of each email next to a role dropdown. The user would assign the roles here and then click "send invites."

This just becomes awkward if the user is only entering one email address, but if the most common use case is to send invites in bulk it might be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is to allow user to type / paste emails and then covnert each email to pill to allow editing.

[image]